# Jasypt plugin with encryption / decryption in grails

Tags: grails, encryption

By the reference of the question [Is it possible to use the Grails Jasypt plugin outside the GORM layer for simple String encryption and decryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192117/is-it-possible-to-use-the-grails-jasypt-plugin-outside-the-gorm-layer-for-simple)

i tried to implement it for my password encryption / decryption .
But every-time its giving different encrypted value for the same password . so how can i use the following code and the jasypt configuration ?

```
def authenticate(){
def jasyptConfig = grailsApplication.config.jasypt
org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor stringEncryptor = 
       new org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor(jasyptConfig)

def encrypted = stringEncryptor.encrypt(params.password)


}

jasypt {
algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC"
providerName = "BC"
password = "test"
keyObtentionIterations = 1000
```

}

Comment: Post your jasypt configuration as well. It's possible you are using a random salt which will always result in different values.

Comment: This is my jasypt Config :
    jasypt {
    algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC"
    providerName = "BC"
    password = "test"
    keyObtentionIterations = 1000
    }

Comment: hi jashua Moore, how to configure this without random ?!

Comment: It doesn't look like it's as simple as a configuration change to do that. Since this is intended to be encryption/decryption and not hashing. However, that said you should be able to configure your own salt generator according to the API http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEStringEncryptor.html

Comment: You might be able to add saltGenerator = new FixedSaltGenerator(salt: 'myfixedsaltvalue') to your config but that's a long shot. I suspect that won't be supported. However here is the type of salt generator you would need: http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/salt/FixedStringSaltGenerator.html

Answer (score 1):

The salt!

If you don't care, just set a ZeroSaltGenerator instance to your Encryptor. By default, it is RandomSaltGenerator, so the outputs are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ZeroSaltGenerator then you have to make following changes:
Inside your config.groovy:

```
jasypt {
    encryptorRegisteredName = "gormEncryptor"
}
```

And in your resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
    hibernateStringEncryptor(HibernatePBEStringEncryptor) { 
        registeredName = "gormEncryptor" 
        algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC"
        providerName = "BC"
        password = "test"
        keyObtentionIterations = 1
        saltGenerator = new org.jasypt.salt.ZeroSaltGenerator()
    }
}
```

And it will generate the same encrypted values everytime.